# Sort files in ascending order in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I have been using this method to sort Files in ascending order:

```java
File folder = new File("F:/test/");
File files[] = folder.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
for (File f : files) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

### Files

1. 1_Test.txt
2. 2_Test.txt
3. 10_Test.txt
4. 12_Test.txt
5. 20_Test.txt

---

But I the ***results*** that I get are:

1. 10_Test.txt
2. 12_Test.txt
3. 1_Test.txt
4. 20_Test.txt
5. 2_Test.txt

Why I am getting this kind of results? How do I obtain results in an order that is numerically ascending, based on the numeric portion of the filename and not the alphabetized order?

Comment: Lexicographically, that _is_ in the correct order.

Comment: That is in the correct order technically.

Comment: Because `10` and `12` are *less* than `1_` due to integer value of `char`s: `0` is 48, `2` is 50, `_` is 95.

Comment: Because you're doing a lexical sort. Hence it's sorting all the names beginning with 1 first, then ordering those with the lowest valued 2nd character and so on.

Comment: What you would have to do is change the comparator, such that if both objects have a number at the same starting index, parse the substring from the starting index to the next non-numeric character, and then compare the integer value of that.

Comment: Thanks! Can't we compare with strings as comparator?

Answer (score 2):

The compareTo function of Java strings compares the values Lexicographically. If  this is not the sorting algorithm that you want, you will need to use something else for the comparator.

Depending on the naming scheme of the files, a good option you may want to try is  to extract the number from the beginning of the string, and parse it into an int. Something along the lines of...

```
String[] parts = o1.split("_");
int lhs = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
parts = o2.split("_");
int rhs = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
```

Comment: Assumes no two files with same leading number.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing two Strings using `compareTo()` will compare them *lexicographically*, which is based on the value of each character. This means that `10_` precedes `1_`, for instance.

What you really want to do is compare the numeric portion of the File's name:

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        String name1 = f1.getName();
        String name2 = f2.getName();
        Integer num1 = Integer.valueOf(name1.substring(0, name1.indexOf("_")));
        Integer num2 = Integer.valueOf(name2.substring(0, name2.indexOf("_")));
        return num1.compareTo(num2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a better compare method that extracts the number. Note: this is a naive example, using the assumption that your file names are all in the format `Number_otherStuff.txt`.

```
public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) {
    Integer f1Num = Integer.parseInt(o1.getName().substring(o1.getName().indexOf('_')));
    Integer f2Num = Integer.parseInt(o2.getName().substring(o2.getName().indexOf('_')));

    return f1Num.compareTo(f2Num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no special characters in the 00-2F range:

```
int max = max_length_of_file_name + Math.log10(max_leading_number);
return leftPadWith0ToMaxLength(o1.getName(), max).compareTo(leftPadWith0ToMaxLength(o2.getName(), max));
```

Code for leftPadWith0ToMaxLength, max_length_of_file_name, max_leading_number left as exercise.